# Is it possible to change Firebase path from an object?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a very simple thing, something like:

```
root: {
  objects: {
    id_subobj1: { // these are two objects doing current events.
      name: "subName1",
      description: "it's nice"
    },
    id_subobj2: {
      name: "subName2",
      description: "it's cool"
    }
  },

  history: { 
// once they are done, I'd like to store them in this branch as an exact copy as they were in the "Objects" branch.
    id_subobj: {
      name: "name",
      description: "it was nice"
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to get my objects, and something like copy and paste them into the history branch.

I'm trying to do so, but I had no success of doing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you've already tried this, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The brief answer is. Observer the objects node by .value. Append them to an array. Iterate over the array and setValue to the history node for each one. The key to working with Firebase is going through the [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) guides as they cover exactly how to accomplish this task. Voting to close as it's too vague.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I achieve this already, forgot I posted this. What I did is to get the `snapshot.val ()` from the 'objects' branch and make an update to the 'history' branch and I got every subobject 'objects' has, the key included - thing that was very important to me. Thanks for your time.